# Best Practices for Java Servlets running under Tomcat 7.x using hibernate and c3p0 and mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, servlets, c3p0

Could someone please summarize the methodology for me, for a JAVA servlet I'm using that runs under Tomcat? This particular Servlet has no framework, but employs a server/client service where I have written supporting backend classes and methods for the client-side user requests. In those backend custom classes, I am using Hibernate(hopefully with c3p0 connection pool management), and Hibernate connects to a resident MySql server. 
     Right now, it appears as though I've forced everything to work by pushing Hibernate JAR's and C3P0 JAR's and JDBC JAR's under the Servlet's lib directory, but I wonder if I've really done the right thing? I've seen in the Tomcat logs that it saw where Hibernate allowed C3P0 to spawn a thread(which is what it does), and it warned me that it couldn't KILL it if it needed to and that it might be a memory leak. So, while I believe C3P0 is definitely running since I configured Hibernate to do so, and it has found the references to the C3P0 classes, could I have done something not-so-optimal? 
     My Tomcat instance is ONLY there for the servlet I mention, and should I have installed Hibernate, C3P0, and Mysql JDBC resources at the Tomcat library level? If so, what do I need to get myself going with the new setup? Config Files in Tomcat? What does the Servlet's backend user-defined JAVA classes need to do to use those resources at the servlet's parent level(Tomcat)?

Each tool has its own documentation and I've found simpleton examples of how to set things up for each, but nothing telling me what is best for this scenario.

Thanks so much for listening/reading, and hopefully helping me through this.

This forum is awesome, and I depend upon the knowledge of the participants to make myself useful everyday.

Carl

Comment: Jun 30, 2015 10:31:18 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderclearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lps] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgehtd9aj9poo6ouiglh|70a37e7f]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: Re c3p0 and Thread issues. 1) In your webapps, you should have a ServletContextListener that shuts down application resources on webapp teardown. If you don't, you should expect resource leaks. c3p0 `DataSources` definitely do need to be close()ed. If wrapped by hibernate, it is the SessionFactory that needs to be closed (which in turn will close() the DataSource). Re tomcat threading issues please see the green box: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#tomcat-specific

Comment: By the way, I am not tested it but you may want to check hikaricp as connection pool. They claim [hikaricp](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is much more faster than c3p0 especially on mysql databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are a lot of blog post about these questions. I try to summarise as far as I know. Some of them may or may not be a best practice.

Servlet's are fundamental technology of java web development. If you are not developing a framework, I will not advise to use it. Yes, it is for that purposes but while developing servlet its hard to separate business logic and your view. When things get complicated, servlets becomes a lot harder to maintain. You should try other frameworks which are developed on top of servlets architecture. If you specify your initial purpose of developing a servlet application, I may help.

Tomcat, as a servlet container, handles all the connections and passes requests to corresponding servlet. Your application, a .WAR file, will runs on top of a servlet container. Also, a servlet container must follow some rules and specifications. So, if you develop an application using servlets, you can be run it which servlet container you want. Tomcat also can manage your resources, like JDBC connections. You can access these resources using JNDI.

But if you want to manage resources by yourself, there is no need to add your dependencies to tomcat/lib folder. You can hold your dependencies under WEB-INF/lib folder.

There are patterns about developing a web application. You must checkout what is MVC. It is a good practice to separate your application into different layers. Each layer must be responsible for single thing. Here is an example, lets say you want to develop a web application which will read data from hibernate. Your first layer must be responsible for getting data from your database. This layer usually called DAO layer. On top of that layer you may put your business logic which is sometimes called service layer. And last your view, in this case your servlet. You can find [an example DAO layer here](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Hibernate-Examples/tree/master/HibernateJPAExample).

At first, it may seem a little hard to glue all the frameworks, but trust me it is not that hard. And always you can use Spring to glue them all.

And about threads, without source code it is hard to identify problem.

Comment: Thanks man. I know all about the MVC design pattern, and I'm also a proponent of it. But I have a legacy servlet I'm supporting and a rewrite is out of the question. I use Grails, which uses Spring, so I know and agree with your assessment. Sold Already!

Comment: I think you may have answered my question by letting me know I was okay in restricting the resources for this one app. I did that intentionally since other servlets may not use the same resources. Especially since it's a dedicated virtual server in our company's cloud. So thanks for that reassurance. Maybe that complaint from tomcat was just it realizing it wasn't completely in control of the servlet's. So thanks for taking time to answer my question, and generating good karma for yourself. :-)